# Crash after trying to close a ofstream file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

In this code I open 4 fieles for writing and after a `for` cycle i close them, but then compiler crashes on the first close of first file (`outLess5.close();`). Suppose you know all variables.
This error appeared suddenly. I did not even understand where.

```
    std::ofstream outLess5("5.txt");
    std::ofstream outLess7("7.txt");
    std::ofstream outFrom2To3("2_3.txt");
    std::ofstream outFrom5To7("5_7.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        double R = sqrt(pow((Xcentral - X[i]), 2) + pow((Ycentral - Y[i]), 2) + pow((Zcentral - Z[i]), 2));
        if (R < latticeParameter * (parameter / 2 - 2))
        {
            MyPrettyMassive[0][0][newCounter0] = i;
            MyPrettyMassive[0][1][newCounter0] = X[i];
            MyPrettyMassive[0][2][newCounter0] = Y[i];
            MyPrettyMassive[0][3][newCounter0] = Z[i];
            outLess5 << X[i] << "\t" << Y[i] << "\t" << Z[i] << "\n";
            newCounter0++;
        }
        if (R < latticeParameter * parameter / 2)
        {
            MyPrettyMassive[1][0][newCounter1] = i;
            MyPrettyMassive[1][1][newCounter1] = X[i];
            MyPrettyMassive[1][2][newCounter1] = Y[i];
            MyPrettyMassive[1][3][newCounter1] = Z[i];
            outLess7 << X[i] << "\t" << Y[i] << "\t" << Z[i] << "\n";
            newCounter1++;
        }
        if (R > latticeParameter * ((parameter / 2 - 2) / 2 - 1) && R <= latticeParameter * ((parameter / 2 - 2) / 2 + 1))
        {
            MyPrettyMassive[2][0][newCounter2] = i;
            MyPrettyMassive[2][1][newCounter2] = X[i];
            MyPrettyMassive[2][2][newCounter2] = Y[i];
            MyPrettyMassive[2][3][newCounter2] = Z[i];
            outFrom2To3 << X[i] << "\t" << Y[i] << "\t" << Z[i] << "\n";

            BeforeRelax[0][newCounter2] = i;
            BeforeRelax[1][newCounter2] = X[i];
            BeforeRelax[2][newCounter2] = Y[i];
            BeforeRelax[3][newCounter2] = Z[i];
            newCounter2++;
        }
        if (R > latticeParameter * (parameter / 2 - 2) && R < latticeParameter * parameter / 2)
        {
            MyPrettyMassive[3][0][newCounter3] = i;
            MyPrettyMassive[3][1][newCounter3] = X[i];
            MyPrettyMassive[3][2][newCounter3] = Y[i];
            MyPrettyMassive[3][3][newCounter3] = Z[i];
            outFrom5To7 << X[i] << "\t" << Y[i] << "\t" << Z[i] << "\n";
            newCounter3++;
        }
    }
    outLess5.close(); // on this line the crash happends
    outLess7.close(); // sometimes on this
    outFrom2To3.close();
    outFrom5To7.close();
```

Comment: Most likely one of your `newCounterX` goes out of bounds. You should add checks that counter value is valid before using counters for indexing array. Also you should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *Suppose you know all variables* -- No it doesn't work this way here.  You need to tell us what those variables are.  We have no idea what `counter` is, the size of those arrays, etc.